# Маршрутизация двух сетевых карт на одном компе

Tags: маршрутизация, подсети, сеть

Ситуация в следующем. На компе стоит две сетевых карты (предположим 1 и 2). на карте 1 работает только интернет (через NTE-2 модем). На карте 2 работает тоже интернет НО через АДСЛ модем (2 нужен для работы - настроен собственный канал но помегабайтный трафик). Вопрос. Каким образом настроить маршрутизацию чтобы интернет работал ТОЛЬКО ЧЕРЕЗ карту 1. А для работы использовалась только карта 2. Буду рад советам!

Answer (score 2):

Для карты 1 в настройках соединения указываете всё: IP-адрес, ДНС, шлюз. Для второй - оставьте только IP-адрес (если там не специфический ДНС сервер, можно его не писать), шлюз прописывать не нужно.

Теперь для карты 2 вам придется настраивать все маршруты, которые вам нужны для работы:

```
ROUTE -p ADD ip_address_or_network MASK mask_value gateway
```

Где:

- ip_address_or_network - IP удаленной сети/хоста
- mask_value - соответствующая ему маска
- gateway - маршрутизатор (в вашем случае это внутренний IP вашего модема, подключенного ко 2й карте)